# Proper audio amplifier for a 12W-RMS / 60W maximum speaker

Tags: amplifier, audio, sound, music

I have two different amplifiers TDA2030A ~ 18W amplifier and a TPA3118 ~ 60W and a medium size speaker labeled 12 watt RMS - 60 watt maximum.

I don't know how the RMS wattage is so far different from the maximum wattage (RMS is 1/5 the maximum.)

I can't choose which amplifier would be better and safer for this speaker.  As mentioned in google, the amplifier should provide more power than the speaker, but how much and more than what? RMS or maximum?

Comment: RMS wattage is not recognized in electrical engineering circles. In other words it's pretty meaningless. Audio marketing people tend to misuse "RMS power" to mean something to them (God knows what). EEs call it average power and average power is an RMS voltage squared divided by load resistance hence, we talk about RMS voltages and RMS currents but, we don't talk about RMS powers.

Comment: An honest 18W amplofoer would be adequate for many tasks. IF you wanyt to reproduce music peaks / sources with wide dynamoc range the 60W amplifier is good OF used sensibly.

Answer (score 3):

The speaker RMS reflects the heating power it can dissipate continuously.

Its max power will reflect mechanical damage from over-travel or excess acceleration.

These are two totally different mechanisms, so it's not surprising they can be a long way apart.

Is your 12 W speaker a single unit, or several units after a crossover?

If several units fed by a crossover, then certainly go for the more powerful amplifier. It's amplifier clipping that generates excess high frequency signal that damages tweeters.

If it's a single unit, then the tweeter issue goes away, and you can safely use either. The lower power amplifier won't deliver on the peaks however, distorting earlier than the bigger one.

Neighbours aside, how do you set your listening level? As you get to the upper end of the loudspeaker's capability, it will generate low order distortion. A small amount is often described as 'warm', and even large amounts are not too objectionable. On the other hand, a transistor amplifier will perform pretty much the same until it clips, which then sounds horrible. With the larger amplifier, you're likely to set your max listening level by the speaker sound. With the lower power amplifier, you're more likely to hear the amplifier clip first.